# Unnesting the custom dimensions is duplicating/inflating transaction revenue in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Unnesting hits.customdimension and hits.product.customdimension is inflating the transaction revenue

```
SELECT
     sum(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)/1000000 as revenue,
     (SELECT MAX(IF(index=10,value,NULL)) FROM UNNEST(product.customDimensions)) AS product_CD10,
     (SELECT MAX(IF(index=1,value,NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS CD1
    FROM
      `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_*`, 
      UNNEST(hits) AS hits, 
      UNNEST(hits.product) as product
     WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180608"
      AND "20180608"
      group by product_CD10,CD1
```

Is there a way I could get a flat table in such a way that if I apply sum of revenue, its should give the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your UNNEST() to the top sub-queries - then the rows won't get duplicated:

```
SELECT row
 ,  (SELECT MAX(letter) FROM UNNEST(row), UNNEST(qq)) max_letter
 ,  (SELECT MAX(n) FROM UNNEST(row), UNNEST(qq), UNNEST(qb) n) max_number
FROM (
  SELECT [
    STRUCT(1 AS p,[STRUCT('a' AS letter, [4,5,6] AS qb)] AS qq)
    , STRUCT(2,[STRUCT('b', [7,8,9])])
    , STRUCT(3,[STRUCT('c', [10,11,12])])
   ] AS row
)
```

[image]

Haven't tested this tho:

```
SELECT
 sum(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)/1000000 as revenue,
 (SELECT MAX(IF(index=10,value,NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit, UNNEST(hit.products) product,  UNNEST(product.customDimensions)) AS product_CD10,
 (SELECT MAX(IF(index=1,value,NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit, UNNEST(hit.customDimensions)) AS CD1
FROM `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_*`, 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180608" AND "20180608"
group by product_CD10,CD1
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. Please accept the answer if it worked :)